# Got this error on my pyzbar program after I converted to exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

The error message is :

```
PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\PETERM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI143202\\pyzbar\\libico
nv-2.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
```

Comment: You did not provide detailed information nor a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try using `--add-binary "path/to/pyzbar/*.dll;pyzbar"` when executing `pyinstaller` to build the executable.  Replace "path/to/pyzbar/*.dll" with real path to `pyzbar` DLLs.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was answered by [r92546024](https://github.com/r92546024) on GitHub : [link](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/issues/27)

Excerpt :

> 1. if you have MSVCR120.dll missing when execute the exe , you need to install C++ package
>    https://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784
> 2. You can put the libiconv.dll & libzbar-64.dll in the exe work folder.
>    The exe file will use the dll in the same folder by first
>    Note:
>    You can get the two dll from C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pyzbar and then copy to the exe folder

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the dll directly to the executable file's directory and also use the --add binary when using pyinstaller to build the executable.
You can find the 2 dll from C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyzbar if you are using pycharm